# How to maintain Service in background for Android app

Tags: android, android-service

So I am able to get a service that will run first using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.  Hopefully, that is the correct way of doing this.  However, since I use an intent to start the service() on my splash screen before the program starts fully, it doesn't allow the splash screen image to work, just the service, and then it goes to the Home Screen.

How can I get both to work? Am I using the `Service` correctly?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Here's what I have so far:

My service class:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class SpeedManagerService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "SpeedCheckerService";

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            Log.i( TAG, "Service onCreate" );
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            Log.i( TAG, "Service onStartCommand" );
            Intent intnt = new Intent(this, SpeedChecker.class);
            intnt.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intnt);
            return Service.START_STICKY;
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This is my Splash Screen:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.splash );

        /**
         * Timer set to spend 3 seconds on splash screen then off to main menu
         */
        Thread timerThread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    startService();
                    sleep( 3000 );
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Intent intent = new Intent( SplashActivity.this, MenuActivity.class );
                    startActivity( intent );
                }
            }
        };
        timerThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }

    public void startService() {
        Intent intent = new Intent( this, SpeedManagerService.class );
        startService( intent );
    }
}
```

My whole idea is to have the `Service` run in the background and whenever it reaches what it needs to, fires out a notification, once the notification is clicked, it goes to one of other classes (otheractivity.class).
Please let me know if I need to post more code.  Thanks!

Comment: The SpeedChecker.class is the one that has everything I need to run in the background, so technically, that's the service..

Comment: Probably not directly related to the problem you're seeing, but you should use a `Handler` to create simple delays, not a `Timer`.  There is almost never a good reason to use `Timer` in Android.

Comment: Actually, `Timer` may have something to do with your problem.  You're calling `startService(Intent)` and `startActivity(Intent)` in the worker thread.  Those methods should be called only in the main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when you start a service like that, it is NOT in the background but on the main thread, see https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html
that's the reason your other activity doesn't load- probably you are doing some job that you thought would be executed in the background (Network access or disk access or some CPU intensive job).

Instead of what you are doing right now, I believe that IntentService will fit whatever you want to do much better - plus its onHandleIntent(Intent) is already running in the background, see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Comment: I've been told what I need to do is Service, then some say IntentService.  What's the big difference? Why would IntentService be better?

Comment: Difference?! Well,IntentService is a subclass of the class Service. However,the code in startservice() runs on the main thread,so you need to create a background thread yourself if you want to use the class Service as is. In the class IntentService,you just have to override onHandleIntent(Intent i) but that method is already running in the background. It's way more convenient than implementing it yourself via the class service.